# Repetition of last value while writing JSON from ResultSet

Tags: java, json

I have searched a lot but couldn't get satisfactory solution.

My objective is to make `JSON` using `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` from `ResultSet`. After loop when I print result in console it gives repetition the last value of `ResultSet`. My code snippet is follows:

```
JSONObject objMain = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arrMain = new JSONArray();

preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Id, Role, Admin_User_Role_ID FROM ADMIN_ROLES");
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if (rs != null) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        obj1.put("Id", rs.getInt("Id"));
        obj1.put("Role", rs.getString("Role"));
        arrMain.add(obj1);
        objMain.put(null,arrMain);
    }
}

System.out.println("JSON: " + objMain);
```

And getting following result which is incorrect:

```
JSON: {"null":[{"Role":"Bulk Peripheral Provisioning Admin","Id":29},{"Role":"Bulk Peripheral Provisioning Admin","Id":29},{"Role":"Bulk Peripheral Provisioning Admin","Id":29}]}
```

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong! 
Note: Please not suggest any builtin methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution problem was the initialization of `obj1` by placing following statement inside of `while (rs.next()) {...}` Repetition removed!

```
obj1    = new JSONObject();
```